# col-xs-0 Not Working Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I emulate my mobile settings for my site, the social icons should be gone; however, they stay.  I have tried putting `col-xs-0` in the i frames themselves, and nothing.

Here's the picture: [image]

Here's my footer HTML.

```
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2 pull-right footersocial">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x socialicons"  aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x socialicons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x socialicons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 15px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Privacy Policy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Terms of Service</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Acceptable Use Policy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Warranty & Returns Policy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Third Party Copyright Notices</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <p>Terms of Service for Phone</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

My CSS:

```
.socialicons {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.footersocial {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.col-xs-0 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The `col-md-2` is probably overriding your custom CSS code with `display:block`. This might happen if you include your CSS code before the `bootstrap.css` or it might be because of specificity reasons. There are ways to make your custom CSS code more specific so that it doesn't get overridden. But the better option is to use `hidden-xs` as Praveen's answer says.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use [`hidden-xs`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) to hide the block in the mobile view or `xs` (extra small) views:

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-md-2 pull-right footersocial">
```

Comment: Interesting. Strangely enough, I never used that before; I think I just might.

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 4 you can use:

> .d-none .d-{screen size}-block

to hide an element depending on the size of the screen (xs, sm, md etc)

Documentation : [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

Answer (score 4):

I just did:

```
.col-xs-0, 
.col-sm-0,
.col-md-0,
.col-lg-0 {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

As my goal was to make sliding animation "from nowhere" and it worked fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

The answer of JuliaCrush is nice, but you have to add padding:

so:

```
.col-xs-0, 
.col-sm-0,
.col-md-0,
.col-lg-0 {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  max-width: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

If not, you will still have a small column because of the padding. Using d-none is preferred, but then I could not animate showing the column as toggling d-none with jquery leaves a style="visibility:none".